# Join two files in bash

Tags: bash, join

I am trying to join two files with two common columns

file 1

```
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf581 6 18
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf582 2 15
globpaunf112 nf561_aggr1 1 21
globpaunf112 nf561_aggr2 - 10
globpaunf112 nf562_aggr1 - 22
globpuknf112 aggr1_n563 - 36
globpuknf112 aggr1_n564 - 40
globpaunf112 aggr1_n561 2 29
```

file 2

```
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf581 47TB 38TB 9229GB 81%
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf582 47TB 40TB 7237GB 85%
globphanf112 nf561_aggr1 12TB 8487GB 4737GB 64%
globphanf112 nf561_aggr2 7347GB 4930GB 2417GB 67%
globphanf112 nf562_aggr1 12TB 9605GB 3619GB 73%
globpuknf112 aggr1_n563 40TB 31TB 9329GB 77%
globpuknf112 aggr1_n564 40TB 32TB 8266GB 80%
globpaunf112 aggr1_n561 65TB 43TB 21TB 67%
```

I need output like this: (all columns from file2 and columns 3 and 4 from file2.

```
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf581 47TB 38TB 9229GB 81% 6 18
globpusnf113 aggr1_nf582 47TB 40TB 7237GB 85% 2 15
```

My command is

```
bash-4.2$ join -t " " -1 1 -2 1 /tmp/file2 /tmp/file2
 aggr1_nf581 6 181_nf581 47TB 38TB 9229GB 81%
 aggr1_nf582 2 151_nf581 47TB 38TB 9229GB 81%
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: best to enumerate each column like `join ... -o 1.1 1.2. 1.3. 1.4 1.5 2.2 2.3.2.4 file1 file2`. You get to figure out the correct numbers to use. `man join` may be of some help. Good luck.

Comment: I notice that the first column of line 3 in file1 and file2 are different. Is it a typo or still need to merge this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`join` requires sorted input. Your samples are not sorted (`globpa`... comes after `globpu`... but should be before).

Comment: They are already sorted

Comment: Then please [edit] your question into a [mcve] which shows exactly how you get wrong results with valid inputs.